# Creating job in jenkins by using HttpClient

Tags: java, jenkins, httpclient

I am trying to create job by using HttipClient.when i run below code i am getting like
Response Status:400Bad Request
i can't create job.Any one please help me the code is like below

```
public class JenkinsHttpClient {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        String jenkinsUrl = "JENKINS_URL";
        String jobName = "testjobonnode2";
        String buildToken = "build";
        String username = "username";
        String password = "password";

        createJobRemote(jenkinsUrl, username, password, "apijob1", 20, 30);
    }


    public static void createJobRemote(String jenkinsUrl, String username,
            String password, String jobName, int daysToKeep, int numToKeep)
            throws Exception {

        StringBuffer JOB_CONFIG_XML_SB = new StringBuffer("here i wrote some xml configurations");

        String job_config_xml = JOB_CONFIG_XML_SB.toString();


        DefaultHttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();


        client.getCredentialsProvider().setCredentials(
                new AuthScope(AuthScope.ANY_HOST, AuthScope.ANY_PORT),
                new UsernamePasswordCredentials(username, password));


        BasicScheme basicAuth = new BasicScheme();
        BasicHttpContext context = new BasicHttpContext();
        context.setAttribute("preemptive-auth", basicAuth);



        String getUrl = jenkinsUrl + "createItem?name=" + jobName;
        HttpPost post = new HttpPost(getUrl);
        post.setHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");

        post.setEntity(new StringEntity(URLEncoder.encode(job_config_xml,
                "UTF-8")));
        System.out.println("Request:" + post.getRequestLine());

        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                (post.getEntity().getContent())));

        String b = null;

        while ((b = br.readLine()) != null) {
            System.out.println(b);
        }
        try {

            HttpResponse response = client.execute(post, context);
            System.out.println("\n Response Status:"
                    + response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode()
                    + response.getStatusLine().getReasonPhrase());
            HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
            EntityUtils.consume(entity);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        System.out.println("Job request posted successfully");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To create a job user needs to set a Content-Type: application/xml header